# Prestashop Fedex Module

Tags: prestashop-1.6, fedex, carrier

Hi i'm trying to use Fedex carrier module to use on a site and i have entered all the info what the module needs to work but the test web service connection failed 
Im based in Colombia, any one know how to use and fox this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is usually related to the address configuration.

Also, an year ago the FedEx Module that is integrated with PrestaShop worked only work in the United States. I'm not sure if it's changed to support non-US addresses.